# reinstall older versions of Android NDK GCC

Tags: android, gcc, android-studio, android-ndk

Overview :

I had a project running and building just great up until a week ago.  An Update to android studio may have wiped my settings.. im unsure.

error I'm getting :

```
 make: ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
```

I look and that folder indeed doesn't exist.  I had an older NDK zip but wondering if Android Studio is ignoring it.  Do I need to add that older version somehow?  reference it in my project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out, I can just point to the NDK build I want in the following file

```
[local.properties]

ndk.dir=.../Android/android-ndk-r10d
```

Comment: I have the same problem. And I'm still fixing it. I found out that the latest NDK as of this moment is r11. In it's release notes it no longer supports GCC 4.8 and all targets uses 4.9 from that version. I guess the latest cocos2dx don't support 4.9 yet. For now I'm downloading NDK r9d which is specified in cocos2dx site on how to build in  android. I assume that will work and supports GCC 4.8.